# Error while selecting a data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a data from my database. I am trying the following code but i get an error.

code:

```
$song_id = $_GET['song_id'];

function getsongdetails($field) 
{
    $query = "SELECT `$field` FROM `songs` WHERE `id`='$song_id'";
    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field)) {
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
}
```

and the error is so:

`Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 10 in /home/a1939662/public_html/details.php on line 12`

The 12. Line is: `if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field)) {`

What is my mistake?

Comment: if you want to see the error page: [link](http://ozankurt.com/details.php/)

Comment: sidenote: why are you people still using the deprecated mysql functions?

Comment: Your $song_id isn't global, pass it as a parameter or set it to global inside of the function. Also check for SQL Injections, don't just insert variables to query. Use PDO

Comment: What do you mean david? how can i do it?

Comment: @feroz: because a deprecation warning for ext/mysql is only thrown from PHP5.5 on - see http://www.php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php :) so the transition is very slow. use PDO_MYSQL http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$song_id = $_GET['song_id'];

function getsongdetails($field,$song_id) 
{
    $query = "SELECT `$field` FROM `songs` WHERE `id`='$song_id'";
    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field)) {
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
function getsongdetails($field) 
{
    global $song_id;
    $query = "SELECT `$field` FROM `songs` WHERE `id`='$song_id'";
    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field)) {
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to use PDO or MySQLi. Don't use the above code since it's exploitable to SQL Injections using the $field and the $song_id variables being inserted directly to the query.

I would also suggest you check for the row count before you call the mysql_result. The row count will tell you how many rows were returned. No point in doing further mysql calls if 0 rows were returned.

Comment: While `global` is an option, it should be discouraged, especially in cases such as this. Use the parameter option instead.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this,then you'll know the error

```
global $song_id;
$query = "SELECT `$field` FROM `songs` WHERE `id`='$song_id'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num>0) {
        if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field)) {
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$song_id = $_GET['song_id'];

function getsongdetails($field, $song) 
{
    $query = "SELECT `$field` FROM `songs` WHERE `id`='$song'";
    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field)) {
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't know what the other variable would be but I think 'title' or something?

```
$result = getsongdetails('title', $song_id);
```

and then echo or print_r your result set in a loop or however you want it to
appear

Answer (score 0):

```
function getsongdetails($field) {
   global $song_id;
    $query_run = mysql_query("SELECT `$field` FROM `songs` WHERE `id`='$song_id'");
     if (!$query_run) {
           //  the query not succes, handle error. ex: return mysql_error();
      } else {
            if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) > 0) {
              $query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 0);
          return $query_result;
         }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code:

```
<?php

function getsongdetails($field, $song_id) 
{

    $query = "SELECT `$field` FROM `songs` WHERE `id`='$song_id'";

    // query validation
    $query_run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if( mysql_num_rows( $query_run ) ) {

      // use msyql_fetch_object instead mysql_result, it's better
      $song = mysql_fetch_object( $query_run );

      // use this if you pass just a 1 field name 
      // (fetch object return and object based in select fields)
      echo $song->$field;
    }
}

$song_id = $_GET['song_id'];
getsongdetails('name', $song_id);
```

The reuslt is: